# Multi tenant application - data isolation and database query routing

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am building a multi tenant application with NodeJS and MSSQL on the backend which will have one instance running. I think about using schema based multi tenancy architecture, meaning single database with separate schema for each tenant `[Tenant1].[DataTable1], [Tenant2].[DataTable1]`.

My question is what is the better way to implement this to handle correct "routing" of SQL queries from different tenants?

I came with four solutions:

1. Use Connection Pools - each tenant user will have a separate SQL connection with a different database user (who has default schema and access to it only).
2. Use single SQL connection but add `EXECUTE AS USER = 'Tenant1' .. REVOKE` to each query (database user has default schema and access to it only).

Or have shared database with single schema

3. [Row-Level Security](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37813.sql-server-2016-implement-row-level-security-using-predicate-function-and-security-policy.aspx), but it seems that it could have a [performance impact](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4778/performance-impact-of-sql-server-2016-rowlevel-security/).
4. Add `Tenant_table` and insert `tenant_id` into each row.

Comment: This is very likely going to be closed as being primarily opinion based. But when you use a different schema for each tenant you have defeated the advantage of a single tenant database. You now have to duplicate all your procedures for each schema. And you have lost the advantage of multiple databases that if one needs to be restored it won't affect everybody. In my opinion a multi-schema multi-tenant database is the absolute worst way to deal with this.